# Editar formatação de parâmetros passados pela URL CakePHP 3

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3

Tenho um formulário de campo único, um `input type="text"`, quando o formulário é submetido a **URL** fica da seguinte forma:

> **`http://localhost:8765/products/search?search=notebook`**

gostaria que ela fica-se da seguinte forma quando submete-se o formulário:

> **`http://localhost:8765/products/search/notebook`**

Digitando a **URL** acima manualmente funciona perfeitamente (criei um método que é capaz de pegar o conteúdo após **search/** desde que esteja no formato acima, também criei uma rota especifica para ter a **URL** acima)

**Código da rota criada (routes.php):**

```
$routes->connect('/products/search/:search', ['controller' => 'Products', 'action' => 'search'],
        [':search' => '\w+', 'pass' => ['search']]);
```

**Código do ProductsController.php (método responsável pela action search)**

```
public function search($search)
    {
        if($this->request->is('get'))
        {
            //$product = $this->request->params['pass'];
            $this->paginate = [
                'fields' => ['product_name', 'quantity', 'sold', 'description', 'price', 'old_price', 'thumbnail'],
                'conditions' => ['product_name LIKE' => '%'.$search.'%'],
                'order' => ['price' => 'DESC'],
                'limit' => 3
            ];

            $this->set('products', $this->paginate($this->Products));
        }
    }
```

**Código do form:**

```
<?= $this->Form->create(null, ['url' => ['controller' => 'Products', 'action' => 'search'], 'type' => 'get', 'id' => 'search-form', 'class' => 'navbar-form span7 text-center']) ?>
            <button class="btn btn-info" title="Favorite o Site">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
            </button>
            <?= $this->Form->text('search', ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Search']) ?>
            <?= $this->Form->button('Buscar <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>', ['type' => 'submit', 'class' => 'btn btn-default']) ?>
        <?= $this->Form->end() ?>
```

**OBS1:** Imagino que a modificação deva ser feita neste `form` (É só uma suposição).

**OBS2:** Estou usando o **CakePHP 3**

Comment: O formato `[...]search?search=notebook` é o padrão do método. Para uar `[...]search/notebook` creio que somente manipulando a URL na hora do submit com JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usei a lib `jQuery` para assim que o `form` for submetido ela suprimir seu comportamento padrão, criar a nova url e fazer a redireção:

```
$("#search-form").submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault(); // suprimir o comportamento padrão
    action = $(this).attr('action') + '/' + document.getElementById('search').value; // criar a nova url no formato desejado
    window.location.href = action; //faz a redireção:
});
```